# Using drawLine on a UIComponent object in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've been trying to draw a series of points using a UIComponent using:

```
var line : UIComponent = new UIComponent();
...
line.graphics.lineTo(renderPoint.x, renderPoint.y);
```

and then updating `mainContainer` which is a `Canvas` object using:

```
mainContainer.addChild(line);
```

The mainContainer is represented in MXML as:

```
<mx:Panel x="270" y="10" width="690" height="680" id="mainContainerPanel">
    <mx:Canvas width="690" height="680" initialize="onInit()" id="canvas">
    <mx:Script>
        protected function onInit():void
        {
            spiro = new Spirograph(canvas);         
        }
    </mx:Script>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Panel>
```

*Please note*

I'm using the event `Event.ENTER_FRAME` to do the `drawLine()` and it iterates over an array to do the drawing each time:

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < _segment.length; j++)
{
    renderPoint = _segment[j];
    line.graphics.lineTo(renderPoint.x, renderPoint.y);
}
mainContainer.addChild(line);
```

The problem is that although I have all `renderPoint` segments etc. The line never gets drawn or it never gets displayed. I think this might be because of some Flex thing that is not so obvious.

I tried to not use all the code here for readability, hopefully the description is straightforward.

Comment: Something is up with SO's formatting tools :)

Comment: Hm. And what is your question? :)

Comment: Even though `line` is a UIComponent, it's not getting added/made visible inside mainContainer. The drawing routine works, it just doesn't display it (according to debug). How can I get the line to be rendered here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't sure if your code in question is a real copy-paste from your ActionScript code. Fields style declaration is from Java or C# but not from AS. Have your compiler error on a line `UIComponent line`?

Second, the `Script` block of your `Panel`. You shouldn't place it inside nested declarations within MXML component but right as a child of component's root node. And it is better to surround code in `Script` block within CDATA block.

What about drawing in `UIComponent` I'd recommend you to assign `width` and `height` values to it.

Comment: All good points... Most of the problems you mention are for convenience alone. Code highlighting works without CDATA, and it all compiles fine, so I thought why bother with CDATA. You're right, I did the type declaration wrong, let me correct it. Will now try width height and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: I'm not a beginner at all this btw.. I've clearly assigned width and height values, but they're omitted for readability. Applying to the line didn't work though.

Comment: The problem is the code is partial so I have to guess. Another question: did you declared `lineStyle` properly?

Comment: I've given up on Flex... it's too tricky to learn quickly and I do not have time. Back to Flash!

Comment: You shouldn't omit all the code. It is impossible to determine if there may be other problems causing your issue.

Comment: The problem is Flex is not the right tool to use. The question here would take a long, long explanation about the Flex component pipeline and really deserves the buying of a book. Even if I included all my code, it wouldn't have helped. I'm happy to use Flash now.